# ReferenceError when testing odoo UI with web.Tour, phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

Currently, I'm using web.Tour from odoo to testing. Although it run successfully on browser console with command:

```
odoo.__DEBUG__.services['web.Tour'].run('create_new_cpo', 'test');
```

But when I trying to running on Terminal console with this command:

```
./openerp-server --addons-path my_path -d my_database --log-level=test -u my_module --test-enable
```

I get the error:

```
openerp.tests.common: phantomjs: u"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: odoo\n at :1\n(leaf frame on top)"
```

Here is my log:

```
INFO my_database openerp.tests.common: phantomjs: loaded http://127.0.0.1:8069/ success
INFO my_database openerp.tests.common: phantomjs: PhantomTest.run: wait for condition: odoo.__DEBUG__.services['web.Tour'].tours.create_new_cpo
INFO my_database openerp.tests.common: phantomjs: page.evaluate eval expr: odoo.__DEBUG__.services['web.Tour'].tours.create_new_cpo
INFO my_database openerp.tests.common: phantomjs: page.evaluate eval result: false
INFO my_database openerp.tests.common: phantomjs: PhantomTest.run: condition statified, executing: odoo.__DEBUG__.services['web.Tour'].run('create_new_cpo', 'test')
ERROR my_database openerp.tests.common: phantomjs: u"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: odoo\n at :1\n(leaf frame on top)"
```

Here is my .py test script

```
from openerp.tests import HttpCase


class TestCPO(HttpCase):
    post_install = True
    at_install = False

    def test_01_create_cpo(self):
        self.phantom_js(
            "/",
            "odoo.__DEBUG__.services['web.Tour'].run('create_new_cpo', 'test')",
            "odoo.__DEBUG__.services['web.Tour'].tours.create_new_cpo",
            login="admin")
```

Comment: Show us how you define `create_new_cpo`

Comment: I found that web.assets_backend.js not loaded, so I import and it worked